# Problems with foundation 6 grid on img overlay in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, zurb-foundation

I am using the foundation 6 xy grid for the first time and am having difficulties aligning three images which have a text overlay at the bottom of each image. I struggling to get the background of the text to fill the full width of the image while making it responsive, 100% width of the newsArticle__pCont class is greater than the parent cell which I don't understand. Below is the closest that I have got (which isn't very close)

```
class News extends Component {

    renderArticlePreview(article) {
        if(articleCount <= 2) {
            articleCount++;
            return (
                <div key={article.id} className="cell small-12 medium-4 newsArticle__cont--firstThree">
                    <img className="newsArticle__img--overlay" src={article.imageUrl} />
                    <div className="newsArticle__pCont">
                        <a href={"/article/" + article.id}><p className="newsArticle__title--overlay">{article.title}</p></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { news } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <div className="grid-container">
                    <div className="grid-x grid-padding-x newsArticle">
                        { news.map((article) => this.renderArticlePreview(article)) }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default News;
```

.scss

```
@import './Helpers.scss';

.newsArticle {

    .newsArticle__cont--firstThree {
        position: relative;
    }

    .newsArticle__title {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #000000;
    }

    .newsArticle__title--overlay {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .newsArticle__pCont {
        background-color: rgba(0, 94, 154, 0.75);
        height: 45px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        z-index: 10;
        width: 100%;
    }

    @include screen(sm-only) {
        .newsArticle__img {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    }

    @include screen(md) {
        .newsArticle__img {
            margin: 10px;
        }

        .newsArticle__p {
            margin: 10px;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason your text right now is too large is because it is

1. position absolute (which takes it out of the flow, so it's not being
   contained by the padding of the cell itself)
2. width: 100%, which will take it to the full width of the parent (which includes the padding).

The simplest way to fix this in your case would be to switch from padding-x (gutters are actually inside the cell, cell width includes the gutters) to margin-x (gutters are done by margin, so cell width excludes gutters).  This would change your grid to look like:

```
<div className="grid-x grid-margin-x newsArticle">
```

A codepen showing this: https://codepen.io/kball/pen/zEGoaR

Comment: You were spot on, it worked straight away.  Is it just me or is the new xy grid quite annoying with the extra markup required to make it do previously default behaviours like adding the margin and padding classes? I can understand why they have changed it to this way but can't help but feel its a lot of kerfuffle for very little reward

Comment: It trades off a little complexity for power - definitely a little frustrating for simple cases, but far more powerful and easy to compose for complex cases.